# How to create dynamic keys of an object and insert into an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add dynamically created objects inside an object, however it overrides the properties in each iteration in the forEach ... I would like to create an object equal to the image with the **GREEN** color, the **RED** color is what it is returning to me now..

**NOTE:** I do not want to create an array, but instead create keys and values ​​dynamically and add in the given object to insert into a SET afterwards.

[image: example]

```
   static organizeData(){ 
        let organizedData = {};

        let oi = {
            "NAME1": {},
            "NAME2": {}
        }

        console.log(oi)

        API.data.records.forEach(record => {
            record.INDICADORES.forEach(indicadores => {
                if(indicadores.tipo === API.queryIndicatorType){
                    indicadores[indicadores.tipo].KPIS.forEach(kpi => {
                        organizedData = { [kpi.tipo]: kpi[kpi.tipo] }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        API.organizedData = organizedData;
        console.log(organizedData)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't assign to `organizedData`, that replaces the entire object. You should just assign to the specific property you want to create. So change:

```
organizedData = { [kpi.tipo]: kpi[kpi.tipo] }
```

to:

```
organizedData[kpi.tipo] = kpi[kpi.tipo];
```